# Sum a list of results in Python

Tags: python, loops, numpy, sum

I have a loop running in Python, but want to sum the results. Here's my code:

```
R=0.05
Timestep = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10])
Cash_flow = np.array([-10000, 300, 1000, 2500, 6000, 6100, 6250, 6250, 6300, 6300, 6200])

for i in Timestep:
    Present_value = Cash_flow[i]*(1+R)**-(Timestep[i])
    print(Present_value)
```

And here are the results:

```
    -10000.0
285.714285714
907.029478458
2159.59399633
4936.21484875
4779.50961546
4663.84622898
4441.75831331
4264.08798078
4061.03617217
3806.26217195
```

I would like to make sum these values; is there a simple way of doing so?

Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

avoid the loop & use vector capability of `numpy`

```
sum_of_values = np.sum(Cash_flow[:]*(1+R)**-(Timestep[:]))
print(sum_of_values)
```

(`sum` would also work instead of `numpy.sum`)

results in:

```
24305.0530919
```

yields the same as the "classical" way, only faster and without loop:

```
sum_of_values=0
for i in Timestep:
    sum_of_values += Cash_flow[i]*(1+R)**-(Timestep[i])
```

Comment: Thanks! This is great :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add `my_sum = 0` before the for loop and `my_sum += Preset_value` inside for loop after you set Preset_value.

At the end of the program (outside of for loop), you can print it with `print(my_sum)`

Comment: Thanks - really appreciate this alternative.